# Issue in iOS7, fine in iOS6

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7

Below is the error i am getting in my app, which is working fine in ios6.

```
[__NSCFString frame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc075290
```

I am not getting what is wrong in it. But i guess something related to `UINavigationController`. Please guide for above.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: After enabling Zombies i get this error.

```
[_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView frame]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc0fb860

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isAcceptTerms"]) {
    [adBannerView setDelegate:self];
    [adBannerView setHidden:NO];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isBannerShown"]) //-ive logic is applied 
    {
        [self.adBannerView setHidden:YES];
        [self.adBannerView setDelegate:nil];
    }
}
else
{
    [adBannerView setDelegate:nil];
    [adBannerView setHidden:YES];
}

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
NSMutableDictionary *dictTemp =[[sqlmessenger shared]fetchOrders];
int count=[[sqlmessenger shared] isuserdetails];

if (count>0)
{
    [self updateCoordinate];
}

NSArray *arrContorl = [self.navigationController.navigationBar subviews];
for(UIButton *btnTemp in arrContorl)
{
    if([btnTemp isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        [btnTemp removeFromSuperview];
    }
}       

UIImageView *imgHeader= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
[imgHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[imgHeader setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"setting.png"]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imgHeader];

if(lblHeader)
{
    lblHeader=nil ; 
}

lblHeader  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,5,230,30)];
[lblHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[lblHeader setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
[lblHeader setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[lblHeader setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0]];
if([dictTemp count]==0 && contentView.hidden == FALSE)
{
    [lblHeader setText:@"Terms of Service (EULA)"];
}
else 
{
    [lblHeader setFrame:CGRectMake(110,5,200,30)];
    [lblHeader setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0]];
    [lblHeader setText:@"Settings"];
}

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:lblHeader];
 }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: Try to find a more specific title for your questions next time.

Comment: @medvedNick No not using ARC.

Comment: this means that UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView was not properly released, and it got deallocated. Then some NSString was move into that place, so some of code sent a message to NavigationBar, but there was a string, which can not handle `-frame` message. Thats all we can help now, you should to show more code

Comment: @medvedNick have updated with code please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you are trying to access the `frame` property of a `NSString` object, which is not permitted, since this object does not have this property.

Try adding more details. (Add the code that causes the crash, usually crash stack are not that helpful).

**UPDATE**:
Still not sure what's going on, you need to do the actual debug, plant the necessary breakpoints log your variables, see what values they have etc.
I can give you some things you can try:

1.Not sure why are you adding subviews to the navigation bar. You can instead use the navigationItem property of the `UIViewController`, and then leftBarButtonItem of `UINavigationItem`, like :

For left bar button item : (make sure you hide the back button first)

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = yourLeftBarButtonItem;
```

And for the right one :

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourRightBarButtonItem;
```

2.You're allocating the view and the label each time that viewController is appearing. That's inefficient. Both memory and time-wise. Instead, you can allocate them once and change the `alpha` channels.